# Could you explain the meaning of warlock invocation number next to its grade?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock

I am rolling a warlock in my current campaign and we started at level 3. For my invocations, I have picked walk unseen and fell flight. I was told I could not do that by my DM since he told me my level wasn't enough. However, when I referred back to my Complete Arcane, it mentioned:

> A least invocation has a level equivalent of 1st or 2nd; a lesser, 3rd
>   or 4th; a greater, 5th or 6th; and a dark invocation has a level
>   equivalent of 6th or higher (maximum 9th).

So I automatically assumed that at level 1 and 2, I have access to least and 3 and 4, I have access to lesser, turns out not.

When I refered back to Complete Arcane for the invocations I picked, it said:

> Fell Flight: Lesser; 3rd

and

> Walk Unseen: Lesser; 2nd

I am really confused about which level can I pick these two invocations? I would appreciate it if you could explain how the warlock level corresponds to the invocation grade and the number next to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You must be 6th level to learn (one of) those invocations

The text you are looking at is the spell level equivalent for invocations. The information you are looking for is a page earlier (page 7).

> The four grades of invocations, in order of their relative power, are least, lesser, greater, and dark. A warlock begins with knowledge of one invocation, which must be of the
>   lowest grade (least). As a warlock gains levels, he learns new invocations, as summarized on Table 1–1 and described below.

Admittedly, Table 1-1 is pretty confusing. The important levels are 1st, 6th, 11th, and 16th. Those are the markers for the 4 power levels: At first level you can only learn least invocations. Then at 6th you can learn least or lesser, and so on. Since both invocations you listed are lesser invocations, you must be 6th level or higher to learn them.

The text you reference indicates the spell level of the invocations. Fell Flight is equivalent to a 3rd level spell, and Walk Unseen is equivalent to a 2nd level spell.

Comment: What would a caster level need to be for dispelling a 3rd level spell?

Comment: @Miniman Spell level is actually more important for *spell turning*, *globe of invulnerability*, and other effects that care about how many levels of spells they can affect or what level of spells they can affect; it also increases the DC of Concentration checks to use the invocation, such as while taking damage over time, getting hit by an attack of opportunity, or standing in a storm. Dispels mostly just care about caster level.

Comment: @Miniman I think if OP has a question about how invocation spell levels work with other spells/abilities/etc., that would be a good new question :)